# How to save Text field (user input) data in a text file in Android app

Tags: android, file-io

I want that whatever I written in edit text field in an app to be automatically save in a .txt file. So that I can retrieve this file directly from there and send to any one from a single button.
My problem is that how can I save directly in a .txt format.

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet will copy your text into a string when the text is changed, and calls a function to write to the private files directory of your application.

```
String YourTextString;    
    YourTextField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {
                YourTextString = YourTextField.getText().toString();
                writeToFile(YourTextString);
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {      
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {         
            }
        });
public void writeToFile(String data) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter MyOutputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(mContext.openFileOutput("YourFileName.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        MyOutputStreamWriter.append(data);
        MyOutputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    } 
}
```

**Edit:**
If you want to read from the file, you can use this function (if the path parameter is empty, the code will read a file from the private files directory, if you give it a path, it will read the file you specified):

```
public String readFromFile(String path) {
    String ret = "";
    if(path==""){
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = mContext.openFileInput(FileName);

            if ( inputStream != null ) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String receiveString = "";
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                    stringBuilder.append(receiveString).append("\n");
                }

                inputStream.close();
                ret = stringBuilder.toString();
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        File file = new File(path);
        String receiveString = "";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while ( (receiveString = buf.readLine()) != null ) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString).append("\n");
            }
            buf.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the content of your `EditText` and save it to a file. Google provides a [documentation for this last part](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html).